# ubuntu: Xorg without "-auth ....". How to eliminate?

Tags: xorg, authentication, ubuntu-20.04

thats Xorg in processlist of ubuntu 20.04 with already open port 6000 (-listen tcp) :

```
/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -listen tcp :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -listen tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

How to get rid of -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 ? - I don't find any code in /etc/ recursively with "auth", nor with "novtswitch" to just comment out "-auth ..." parameter for Xorg.
Who can help me? - Alternatively add authority to second machine in LAN to access to port 6000?  Or is lightdm restrictive to access from other machines? BTW: firewall ufw status is inactive. telnet 10.0.0.9 6000 from second machine works. But no access to display of users although xhost + is done.

Why? - Its LAN only, auth-security sucks. We have a communication system since 20 years that sends messages to desktop from second machine to many ubuntu desktops of users using e.g. export DISPLAY=10.0.0.9:10.0;messageApp &  and "xhost + 10.0.0.104" in autostart in every desktop. Modern Xorg seems to need authentication, that sucks. Opening port 6000 is no longer enough for a second machine to access port 6000.

tia
Eckard

Comment: Your question appears a bit scattered, possibly with some rants and opinion, and no real statement indicating there is anything actually wrong. Could you please edit your post to focus and clarify it a bit? More explanation of what is actually broken may also be helpful.

Comment: Can you clarify whether this is a new issue in Ubuntu 20.04? Putting the utter irresponsibility of wanting to allow any user run a keylogger against any other user's X display aside, I don't think the Xauth/Xhost facilities have changed behavior in the last 25+ yr, (i.e. not exactly modern), so if you've been using this method for "since 20 years" surely you must've had to deal with it back then.